# FPDF to CSV or xls export

Tags: php, csv, pdf, xls, fpdf

I generally use FPDF to generate to pdf. But I want to generate a xls or csv file. I read somewhere that this can be done using FPDF. I tried changing the extension but it was not working . Is there any way by which I can use FPDF for xls/csv generation or any php tools or plugin which converts fpdf generated pdf file to xls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't realise that Excel could open PDF files.

Comment: ^ I read somewhere on StackOverflow that fdpf can export in csv format too. But I dont no how. This is not about opening pdf files without excel.

Answer (score 0):

I genearally recommend that you use Exel for xls/csv not sure if it can open pdf files, prefarbly I would download a pear file and start learning how to implement it and use its send functions and formats style. Below is a helpful like were you can learn and download the pear file http://pear.php.net/package/File